# How to make bootstrap wrapped columns to stretch full width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I have simple code example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/milost1982/pen/ExYQMPe) but here is the markup for convinience:

```
<div class="container my-container">
  <div class="row m-row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-2 my-col">One of three columns</div>
    <div class="col-5 my-col">One of three columns</div>
    <div class="col-5 my-col">One of three columns</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And some custom css:

```
.my-row {
  justify-content: stretch;
}

.my-col {
  background: yellowgreen;
  border: 1px gray solid;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

With larger screen width I get this which is fine:
[image]

But when I set small sizes, eg. instead of resizing browser window you can `my-container` width to 150px just to demonstrate what happens

```
.my-container {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Then items wrap and I get following result:
[image]

How can I make wrapped items to fill the rest of the width?

Comment: don't make your container 150px wide - if you do then you need to increase the size of your cols - col 2 means a sixth of 150px which is why your col is so narrow and the text overflows

Comment: and remove align-self: stretch;

Comment: I made it 150px wide just to demonstrate what happens at small widths because you can't resize codepen viewpor that low.

Comment: then use the responsive classes to make the col resize depending on browser size: eg try `col-sm-6 col-lg-2 my-col` and remove the stretch and width of the container then resize your browser

Comment: @Dimitris removing align-self: stretch doesn't seem to have any effect

Comment: read this section: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#variable-width-content

Comment: You just need to add class "flex-nowrap" with "row m-row" class.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use the bootstrap breakpoints [see here under Grid options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

So if you want them to be full width of your container use col-12.

```
 <div class="container my-container">
  <div class="row m-row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">One of three columns</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-5">One of three columns</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-5">One of three columns</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this will indeed stretch the last item when it gets wrapped for small widths, but for large widths it will stay in the wrapped row and not move to the first row where there is enough space to accommodate it

Comment: thats because i missed to set col-12 col-sm-5 and the last div in the row

Answer (score 1):

just add white-space: nowrap;

```
.my-row {
  justify-content: stretch;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.my-col {
  background: yellowgreen;
  border: 1px gray solid;
  align-self: stretch;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.col-md-*` or `.col-sm-*` classes for the full width content in small devices instead of `.col` classes. show snippet in full width and make it resize.

```css
.my-row {
  justify-content: stretch;
}

.my-col {
  background: yellowgreen;
  border: 1px gray solid;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
<div class="container my-container">
  <div class="row m-row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-md-2 my-col">One of three columns</div>
    <div class="col-md-5 my-col">One of three columns</div>
    <div class="col-md-5 my-col">One of three columns</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: your `.col-**-*` class width can't change if you change in `.container` width you have to change it manually.

Thank You...

Comment: sorry this doesn't answer my question

Comment: @mlst so actually what did you want please explain more i will help you to solve the problem if possible.